# RabbitMQ Cluster Deployment error on K8 - Readiness probe failed

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, kubernetes-networkpolicy, readinessprobe

K8 Tools version I am using: kubelet=1.19.16-00 kubeadm=1.19.16-00 kubectl=1.19.16-00

RabbitMQ cluster operator is running successfully but the cluster is not able to setup due to some network related issues (my guess..)

[cluster operator is running successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fwdP.png)

When I describe the pods for debugging I get to see error for all nodes *Readiness probe failed: dial tcp :5672: connect: connection refused* It goes in race condition and eventually throws crashbackloop error.
[Readiness probe failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VaPb.png)

I am new to RMQ, K8 and have tried few more work arounds available on web but always get stuck at this stage.

My K8 is installed on AWS EC2 instance and
I have installed operator there using *kubectl apply -f https://github.com/rabbitmq/cluster-operator/releases/latest/download/cluster-operator.yml*

Below is the yaml file I am trying to deploy as a cluster.

```
apiVersion: rabbitmq.com/v1beta1
kind: RabbitmqCluster
metadata:
 name: rabbitmq-cluster
 namespace: rabbitmq-system
spec:
 replicas: 3
 resources:
   requests:
     cpu: 250m
     memory: 500Mi
   limits:
     cpu: 1
     memory: 1Gi
 rabbitmq:
         additionalPlugins:
            -   rabbitmq_mqtt
 service:
   type: ClusterIP
```

Any help or suggestion what I am missing here would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: share the logs of pods

Comment: Container logs : 
BOOT FAILED
===========
ERROR: epmd error for host rabbitmq-cluster-server-0.rabbitmq-cluster-nodes.rabbitmq-system: timeout (timed out)

2023-01-23 17:01:23.585048+00:00 [error] <0.130.0>
2023-01-23 17:01:23.585048+00:00 [error] <0.130.0> BOOT FAILED
2023-01-23 17:01:23.585048+00:00 [error] <0.130.0> ===========
2023-01-23 17:01:23.585048+00:00 [error] <0.130.0> ERROR: epmd error for host rabbitmq-cluster-server-0.rabbitmq-cluster-nodes.rabbitmq-system: timeout (timed out)